# Is there a way to show if I have more than one Google Chrome window open in the Dock?

Tags: macos, dock

Yes, I know I can use tabs, but there are times where I will need to open a new Google Chrome window. Unfortunately, I have bad memory and I always forget that I have a second Chrome window opened.

In Windows 10, the taskbar will show you if you have two Chrome windows open, which appears like this

[image].

Is there a way macOS can notify me if I have two of the same apps open?

Answer (score 1):

You can right click/control click on an app's icon in the Dock to determine the number of open windows for the app. Here's a screenshot from a Google Chrome session:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSmVP.png]

A list of all the open windows for the app are shown at the top in the context menu presented on right clicking/control clicking.

Comment: Also add windows menu, if it helps. Or three finger swipe down

Comment: Is there a way to have the dock passively notify if I have 2 of the same apps open? Sometimes I'm working on one Chrome window, I will forget the other Chrome window is opened since I have it hidden behind my primary Chrome window. I want to be able to know at any time that I have two of the same apps opened without needing to right click every time to check.

Comment: @key You can alternatively use Hot Corners to show you all the application windows. [This](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-see-all-open-windows-on-mac-at-once-3663530/) article should give you an idea.